# How to change a label's contents using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, dom-events

I have a label that holds a value and a text box into which I will enter a number. I have another label, which should dynamically give the difference between the two as I type the number in the text box. How do I do this using Javascript? I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compute_diff(){
    var lbl1 = document.getElementById("<%=label1.ClientID%>").value;
    var txtbox = document.getElementById("<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").value;
    var lbl2value = lbl1 - txtbox
    document.getElementById("<%=label2.ClientID%>").innerText = lbl2value;
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

I am calling this function on the `OnKeyUp` event, but it is not firing it. What is the correct way of going about this? I am developing the site using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
var lbl2value = lbl1 - txtbox
```

will not work. You will need to use a string diff algorithm such as the one at

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

In addition, consider using jQuery to ensure that this works cross browser as the implementation of innerText can differ from browser to browser.

Comment: @Tim Ebenezer: Thanks for site, but will it work with numbers? The label and the input I'll be entering into the textbox are both numbers. Will it work?

Comment: I see, if they are numbers and you want to get the difference, you will need to cast to numbers first using the parseInt function.

Comment: @Time Ebenezer: Can you please tell me how I can do that? And on what event it is to be fired? Thanks! :)

Comment: var lbl2value = parseInt(lbl1) - parseInt(txtbox);

Comment: @Tim Ebenezer: Thanks! :) With the exception of that, the code is fine?

Comment: It should work - but consider using jQuery for a more cross browser friendly approach.